# Can someone explain JS Regex limits using {}

Tags: javascript, regex

Ok, so I wrote a function where I would test an input string and see if it matched one of a few different formats. All of my tests seemed to work fine except for the last format I could not get to work using only my regex & .test()...

`/\d{10}/`   allowed a string longer than I wanted

`/\^d{10}!?.*$/`   would not allow the correct length string (and other combos similar to this)

I tried other combos but ultimately I resorted to using an if statement to check the string length, but I want to know why this wasn't working and what I should have done instead if anyone can help me out! Thanks

Comment: Could you add some examples to your question what should and should not match?

Comment: I suggest using a regex tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). The regex `/\d{10}/` simple checks for 10 digits in a row, so any other letters or anything before or after those 10 digits will still be considered valid. [Check out that example](https://regex101.com/r/u6qAcP/1). If you try that other regex you posted, you will see that you are looking for `^` literally because you have it a backslash in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you do not want that backslash.

This regex:

```
 /\^d{10}!?.*$/
```

... looks for "ten digits *preceded by a literal `^`* at the end of the string.  (Because of the `$` anchor.)

Undoubtedly you mean the `^` to also be an anchor.  This regex:

```
 ^\d{10}$
```

... looks for a string which consists *only* of exactly ten digits.  The `^` character anchors the search to the beginning of the string, and the `$` character anchors it to the end.  In other words, "ten digits beginning at the start of the string, and also ending at the end of the string."  "A string consisting only of ten digits."

Comment: Actually `\^d{10}` looks for a `^` followed by 10 `d`'s, not 10 digits

Comment: Using both a beginning anchor and ending anchor worked! thank you, I was staring at this for way too long trying to figure it out and your solution seems so simple, bless you... I mistyped in my question I did mean to put /^\d{10}/ my apologies.